# AngularJS UI-Router scoping issues

Tags: angularjs, signalr, angularjs-scope

I've got what I think is a scoping issue with angular ui-router, but I'm not quite sure.

```
angular.module('Meeting').controller('MeetingController', ['$scope', 'signalRService', '$stateParams', function ($scope, signalRService, $stateParams) {
$scope.setMeetings = function(meetings) {
    $scope.meetings = meetings.map(function(meeting) {
        return {
            id: meeting.CategoryId,
            name: meeting.MeetingName
        };
    });
    $scope.$apply();
};

$scope.connectToSignalR = function () {
    signalRService.connect();
    signalRService.registerAddMeetingsClientMethod($scope.addMeetings);
};

$scope.requestMeetings = function() {
    signalRService.requestMeetings($stateParams.departmentId);
};

$scope.connectToSignalR();

$scope.eventId = $stateParams.eventId;

}]);
```

Basically, my module is injected with a signalR service, and I register a callback on it to set meetings. I have a button on my view to tell the signalR service to fetch the meetings, which then calls the callback I just registered. 
Now, all this works fine with ui-router, but *only the first time* the page is loaded. Here's my routing config:

```
angular.module('Meeting')
.config(
    ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

            $stateProvider                   
                .state("meeting",
                    {
                        url: "/meeting/:departmentId/",
                        templateUrl: '/home/meetingPage',
                        controller: "MeetingController"
                    })
                .state("meeting.members",
                    {
                        url: "/members/",
                        templateUrl: "/home/memberspage",
                        controller: "MeetingMemberController"
                    })                   
                .state("meeting.edit", {
                        url: "/meetingedit",
                        views: {
                            'meetingtime': {
                                templateUrl: '/home/timepage',
                                controller: 'MeetingTimeController'
                            },
                            'location': {
                                templateUrl: '/home/locationpage',
                                controller: 'MeetingLocationController'
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }]);
```

When I load up a meeting state (i.e. mysite/meeting/3), all the signalR methods are called, the meeting model in the MeetingController is populated, and the data appears in the view.
When I navigate to another state (i.e. mysite/meeting/4), the signalR methods are still called, and the meeting model is populated, but then just disappears. If I manually refresh the page with F5, it starts to work again, but navigating to a different page stops everything working.

I'm thinking it's a scoping issue, because when I navigate to a different page, the meetings object is still populated from the previous page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I was registering callbacks with a singleton signalR service was getting really cumbersome, and doesn't play well with ui-router, as I found out.

I switched to using promises, and everything works so much more elegantly. Basically, I have a method on my signalR hub that returns the object I want:

```
public List<Meeting> GetMeetingsForMember(int memberId)
    {
        return  _meetingRepository.GetAllUpcomingMeetingsForMember(int memberId);
    }
```

Then, in my controller, I create a promise, and pass it to my signalR service for resolution:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
deferred.promise.then(
    function (meetings) {
        setMeetings(meetings);
    }
);
signalRService.getMeetingsForMember(memberId, deferred);
```

The getMeetingsForMember method on my signalR service accepts the promise and resolves it:

```
getMeetingsForMember = function (memberId, deferred) {
    deferred.resolve(signalRService.hub.server.getMeetingsForMember(memberId));
}
```

Comment: You seem to be doing data retrieval inside your SignalR implementation.  This is probably better suited to be done with $http or ng-resource.  SignalR is intended for messaging between the client(s) and the server (and vice versa).